# Cannibis beer vs.. Cannabis-Infused Beer

Tags: taste, specialty-beers, craft-beers

There seems to be two types of weed beers: Cannabis Beer and Cannabis-Infused Beer on the market.

What is the difference between the two and what is the taste difference between the two?

Bonus question: Which one gives individuals the best traditional buzz in comparison to smoking weed?

Cannabis is legal here in Canada.

Comment: I asked the following discussion question on the Beta Site: [Would it be possible to a add marijuana to this site’s parameters as being on topic?](https://alcohol.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269/would-it-be-possible-to-a-add-marijuana-to-this-site-s-parameters-as-being-on-to)

Comment: So if we talk about a particular ingredient in the craft,  it must be legal globally?  I'm not sure what to take away from the Beta Site link.
I'd hope that if someone was brewing a craft with dog-poo as a key ingredient, we'd be able to share some good insights.  Whether or not I'm a fan of a dog-poo flavored craft.

Answer (score 1):

The one that gives the "buzz" is one that obviously has THC. Although keep in mind the ingestion via drinking is going to have least immediate effect, vs "in comparison to smoking weed"

I also presume that a cold/chilled beverage is going to solidify the THC crystals, or trichomes, and may take even longer for body to absorb. But probably not too long as body heat will warm it soon enough.

Perhaps the more Alcohol content it has, it can keep the THC in a "dissolved" state. I'm guessing the "Infused" is the weed/THC added later, vs brewing with the weed already in it.

Taste? IDK.